# Escape key stops loading the web application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hi we are facing the problem with escape key in our web application. If user press the escape key the web  application gets stop loading.
I tried using all these with(onkeydown and onkeyup)

```
document.attachEvent("onkeydown", win_onkeydown_handler);
window.attachEvent("onkeydown", win_onkeydown_handler);
window.document.attachEvent("onkeydown", win_onkeydown_handler);
```

I cant able detect the escape(**KeyCode=27**) in my web application .. but i am able to detect refresh,f5 and all other keys

**Note: i face this problem in IE**

Comment: Do you mean *while* the page still hasn't finished loading? If that's the case, that's normal behavior, it's a browser keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes, the page stopped loading when escape key is pressed. So if escape key is consider as shortcut then F5 is also same. But here i can detect and control F5 key

Comment: What is the content of your `win_onkeydown_handler` function? Make sure you have set `event.returnValue = false;` and `e.cancelBubble = true;`

Comment: @steveukx : I cant able detect the escape keycode itself.. if i pressed escape key its not entered into win_onkeydown_handler() itself

Comment: Can you post your code for what you use to determine what key code it is?

Comment: ESC is *supposed* to stop the page from loading in IE. If the user presses it then the odds are that they will be expecting it to stop. Don't break the principle of least astonishment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps me to prevent escape in iframe

```
function disableEscapeAndRefresh(){
try{
    if(window.frames && window.frames[0]){
        window.frames[0].focus();
        for (var i_tem = 0; i_tem < window.frames.length; i_tem++){
            if(document.all && document.body.filters)
                window.frames[i_tem].document.onkeydown = new Function("var e=window.frames["+i_tem+"].event; if(e.keyCode==116){e.keyCode=0;alert('Refresh Not Allowed');return false;}if(e.keyCode==27){e.keyCode=0;alert('Escape Not Allowed');return false;};");
        }
    }
}catch(e){

}
}
```

**call this method in iframe onload**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to trap that... it's the equivalent of clicking the X to stop the page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are targeting versions of IE that  have `attachEvent` enabled, you can use this to detect the escape key being pressed. The handling of the event is the usual code for preventing default event behaviour, though this may not work on cancelling the page download as this may be seen as a security flaw (imagine the unscrupulous developer that wants to prevent the user from cancelling a malicious download):

```
document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function(){
  if(window.event.keyCode == 27) {
    window.event.returnValue = false; 
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/LJHs8/